# Why is my toggle not transitioning properly

Tags: jquery, toggle, effect

Everything is "working" here but my animation isn't displaying properly. I want the toggle button to move up in position while the navigation disappears, but the "slow" isn't working.

JQuery:

```
//Close and open
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".open, .close").click(function(){
    $(".navigation").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".open").toggle();
    $(".close").toggle();
    $(".navigation").css("display","inline");
    $(".collapse").toggleClass("collapse-closed","slow");
  });
});
```

CSS

```
.open{
    display:block;
    margin: 12px auto 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 13px solid #9b9b9b;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s; /* Opera */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.open:hover{
    border-top: 13px solid #A70400;
    }
.close{
    display:none;
    margin: 10px auto 0px;
    padding:0px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 13px solid #9b9b9b;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.3s; /* Opera */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close:hover{
    border-bottom: 13px solid #A70400;
}
.collapse {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    z-index:8;
    width: 46px;
    height: 36px;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    right: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 24px;
}
.collapse-closed {
    top: -8px;
}

.navigation {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #919191;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px #bdbdbd;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 7;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 0em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navigation ul {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    border-top-style: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s; /* Opera */
    border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(167, 4, 0, 0);
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}

.navigation ul li:hover,
.navigation ul li:active {
    display: inline;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #A70400;
}

.navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#ems">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ems">Writing Samples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ems">Musings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ems">Books</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse">
        <div class="open"></div>
        <div class="close"></div>
    </div>
```

Am I blocking the transition speed somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no animation in that fiddle...

Comment: Please post relevant code, not just a link

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong link. It's updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the jQuery UI to your page and it'll allow you to animate class changes (use [UI 1.8.22](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js) for jQuery 1.8). Your code will work fine with the UI extension.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3AJUB/1/)

Without the UI you can't animate class changes. You could replace those class changes with [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) passing the `top` property, like this:

```
$(".collapse").animate({top: ($('.collapse').css('top') === '-8px') ? 24 : -8}, 'slow');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/3AJUB/3/)

Comment: I see that it's working in the fiddle but I'm not getting it to work on my page despite loading 1.8.22 UI and 1.8.0. I'm not understanding what the difference is between what I'm doing on Fiddle and what I'm doing on my page...

Comment: Yeah it should work if you load the UI right after jQuery lib `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`, otherwise my alternative code should do it as well. `=]`

Comment: Ahh my bad I was missing something for the UI code. Got it working! Thanks!